# How to Give two values to Combo Box

Tags: winforms

As a part of Globalisation I need to display Combobox Text in Spanish but in code I want to use English Text  without changing functionality.Is it possible to add two values   as like we use Text and Value in ASP:Dropdownlist .

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very into ASP, but what is possible in PHP is to use the database (with local caching) to show a title/name in another language.

In our company we've build a "translate()"-function, which accepts a string like "I like tomatoes", converts it to "i-like-tomatoes" and returns the translated version out of the database with the help of a locale ("es_ES"): "Me gusta los tomates".

So, in **pseudo PHP/MySQL code** this will be:

```
function translate($sInput, $sLocale)
{
    // mysqli-query to database
    $result = mysqli_query("SELECT `translation` FROM `translation` WHERE `input` = '".$sInput."' AND `locale` = '".$sLocale."'");

    return $result['translation'];
}
```

```
$locale = "es_ES";

<select>
    <option value="i-like-tomatoes"><?=translate("I like tomatoes", $locale);?></option>
    <option value="i-like-apples"><?=translate("I like apples", $locale);?></option>
</select>
```

I'm sorry not to provide you any ASP code, but I hope you'll understand the meaning.